# How to add text watermark on imageview in android,Using this code but not working

Tags: android

How to add text watermark on imageview in android,Using this code but not working

```
public  Bitmap waterMark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint);

    return result;
}
```

And the code is called like this:

```
Bitmap b=waterMark(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.setting),
    R.drawable.image,p, Color.GREEN,90,80,true);
imView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: Could you please post you're implementation part where you're calling watermark and pass the bitmap to the ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap b=waterMark(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.setting),
                        R.drawable.image,p, Color.GREEN,90,80,true);
                imView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imView.setImageBitmap(b);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
```